# VMware Converter FAILED: A specified parameter was not correct. info.owner

Tags: windows-xp, vmware, vmware-converter

I'm trying to convert a 32-bit Windows XP system to a VMWare VM remotely from a Windows 7 Machine.  When I do I get the error:
`A specified parameter was not correct. info.owner`

## Source System Information

**Source type:** Powered-on machine
**Name or IP Address:** dvrcam
**Connected as:** domain\administrator
**OS family:** Windows
**No throttling infomration**

## Destination system information

**Virtual Machine Name:** dvrcam
**Destination Product:** VMware Workstation 8.0.x
**Destination Direct:** \backup\d$\ComputerImage
**Number of vCPUs:** 2 (2 Sockets * 1 cores)
**Physical Memory: ** 2GB

**Network** Preserve NIC Count
**NIC1** Connected
Bridged Connection
**Disk controller type:** Auto select 
**Storage:** Volume-based cloning 
**Number of disks:** 1 
**Create disk 0 as: ** Not Pre-allocated

## Destination customizations:

**Install VMware Tools:** No 
**Customize OS: ** No 
**Remove restore checkpoints: ** Yes 
**Reconfigure Virtual Machine: ** Yes

## Synchronization Information

**Synchronize changes that occur during cloning:** No

Comment: Viewed 2505 times in 7 months, got a badge but no upvotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem occurs when your username and computer name where Converter is installed are the same. Changing one of them should fix it

Comment: Yeah that's what it was; thanks for listening to my `True Story Bro`.